# Should I post MS SQL Server 2005 code in response to a question which is related to MySQL?  

Tags: discussion

Actually right now on http://stackoverflow.com I see a question which is related to PHP or MySQL.

[How to display hours between two dates in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565463/how-to-display-hours-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

and user wants the answer either in **MySQL or PHP** and some intelligent person gives answer in **PHP** and accepted as answer .
as this related to sql so i tried to solve this in MS SQL as I have this platform and I have found a suitable solution.

***Should I post that code in reply of that question or not?***

As this is not related to MySQL but it is related to SQL Server 2005 in general and somebody in future who working with C# and MSSQL  can have the same query and can get the answer for this.

Answer (score 5):

*Always* add additional details, further information or other solutions to an already answered question... *but* only if they fit the question.

In this case it's a **no**. The question is about [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), not about [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). If your answer is *generic* SQL on the other hand, then yes, add it.